# Hibernate onetoone association OrderBy annotation, does not reflect in select query

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I Have three entities named SUBJ (Superior) , SUBJ_DOC (Super) and DOC(Child) , i wanted to apply a orderby annotation for the child table column. when i applied through below code (order by clause does not appear in the hibernate generated select query).

Please help me to get the result orderd with child entity table cloumn.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBJ")
@Where(clause = "ROW_INAC_INDC = 0")
public class Subj implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Set<SubjDoc> subjDocs = new HashSet<SubjDoc>(0);    

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SUBJ_ID")
    @Where(clause = "ROW_INAC_INDC = 0")
    public Set<SubjDoc> getSubjDocs() {
        return subjDocs;
    }

    public void setSubjDocs(Set<SubjDoc> subjDocs) {
        this.subjDocs = subjDocs;
    }
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBJ_DOC")
@Where(clause = "ROW_INAC_INDC = 0")
public class SubjDoc implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long subjDocId;

    private Doc doc;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOC_ID", nullable = false)
    @OrderBy(clause="ORDER_ID DESC")
    public Doc getDoc() {
        return doc;
    }

    public void setDoc(Doc doc) {
        this.doc = doc;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "DOC")
public class Doc implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Integer orderID;

    @Column(name = "ORDER_ID", precision = 7, scale = 0)
    public Integer getOrderID() {
        return orderID;
    }

    public void setOrderID(Integer orderID) {
        this.orderID = orderID;
    }
}
```